# Replace range of values for factor with levels

Tags: r

I have a column with Median House Income values, with 92 values ranging from 30,000 to 12,000. I was trying to replace the integer values into factor ones with 2 levels reflecting low and high incomes.

First, I changed the values from integer to factor. Then I tried using the fct_collapse function like this:

```
VACounty$MedHouseIncome2012 <- fct_collapse(VACounty$MedHouseIncome2012,
    low = c("30000:8000"),
    high = "8000:12000")
```

This did not work at all. Would someone be able to help me crack this out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For integer values you can use simple `ifelse` to change the values in two groups.

```
VACounty$MedHouseIncome2012 <- ifelse(VACounty$MedHouseIncome2012 < 8000, 'low', 'high')
```

If you need column as factors you can do

```
VACounty$MedHouseIncome2012 <- factor(VACounty$MedHouseIncome2012)
```

Comment: Hi Ronak! thanks for helping out. So I tried, the first option using ifelse and it was only able to change the columns to 'high' but miss to recognize a range to set the ones lower than 8000 to 'low'. So I wasn't able to sort them out between high and low values. Would you be able to let me know how to fix this? :)

Comment: Can you edit your post to provide sample of your dataset by pasting the output of `dput(head(VACounty, 10))`

Comment: ConflictFreq_8_15 = c(262L, 148L, 4L, 63L, 25L, 458L, 57L, 161L, 90L, 141L), MedHouseIncome2012 = c(70813L, 44530L, 49714L, 43791L, 43814L, 49773L, 44524L, 56910L, 42843L, 
60943L)

Comment: I pretty much just sent the response variable that I'm interested in (ConflictFreq..) and one of the covariates (MedHouseIncome2012)... was interested in seeing any relationships between the two so that's why I'm kind of hoping to organize the medincome value between high and low and see if it's easier to see any relationship on my response variable like that

Comment: Not sure if this is a good idea just yet but just wanted to explore that!

Comment: @VeeMorejon I see that the `MedHouseIncome2012` is in the range of 50k, 70k etc but you are checking only for 8k. Should that be 80k instead? Try `VACounty$MedHouseIncome2012 <- ifelse(VACounty$MedHouseIncome2012 < 80000, 'low', 'high')`

Comment: Just noticed the typo! my bad :/

Comment: It worked really well! thanks a lot! Right after that, I was also successful in changing the data to factor with levels! I appreciate your help loads!